# while running an android application, i am getting the following error in console

Tags: android

```
[2013-09-24 01:37:57 - FirstApp] ------------------------------
[2013-09-24 01:37:57 - FirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-09-24 01:37:57 - FirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-24 01:37:58 - FirstApp] Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-09-24 01:37:58 - FirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google'
[2013-09-24 01:37:58 - FirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_4_by_Google'
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] 
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] emulator: Open HAX device failed
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] 
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - Emulator] HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - FirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-09-24 01:38:07 - FirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

and below is my AVD configuration

Target : Android 4.3 - API Level 18

CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)

RAM : 512  VM Heap : 64

Internal storage : 200MiB

SD Card : 1000MiB

i found so many answers, but none helped. plz help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a emulation option (for your emulator) called "USE HOST GPU"... Is it enabled? Take a look at it.

It seems like your emulator is falling at initializing rendering using your host machine GPU. You can uncheck that box if that is the case, and it will use only software rendering.

You can give it a try.

Comment: thanx for the reply, but "Use Host GPU" as well as "Snapshot", both are unchecked.